# GIMP. How To Add a Small Moveable, Resizeable Image To A Larger Image?

Tags: gimp

I have a small 'stamp' image that I want to put on top of documents. Sort of 'stamp' them.  The stamp is largely transparent,  the stamped document is meant to show through.

I find opening the base document and then  'open as layers' the 'stamp' document brings the stamp in as a layer on the first document.

But it is outlined with crawling ants, I can't fix that.  And I can't find a handle to resize it.  And when I move it the whole image moves, the 'base' image and all.

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The ants are not really crawling, they are fixed. They show the boundaries of the layer (because your layer is smaller that the canvas). They are just a visual indication, and not part of the picture. You can make them invisible

   - permanently, using `View>Show layer boundary` (but they are a useful indication in many cases)
   - temporarily, by selecting your base layer in the Layers list. You will then see the  boundaries of that base layer but since they are around the image, they won't be obtrusive.
2. You can resize your layer using:

   - the [Scale tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-scale.html) (activate the Scale tool, and click on your layer, this will add handles in its corners).
   - `Layer>Scale layer`
3. By default the Move tools auto-selects the layer to be moved by picking the topmost **opaque** layer where you click. So if you click on a transparent area of your stamp layer, the Move tools will select the background. Two solutions:

   - Click on a non-transparent part of your stamp
   - In the Move tool options, select the `Move active layer` and make sure your stamp is the active layer.
   - Keep the auto-select behavior, but temporarily disable it when needed by depressing the shift key before clicking to start the move.

Comment: Thank you, Sir.  Concise, precise and nice.  Just what I wanted.  A perfect answer. :)

Comment: Thanks, but then "Accept" it  ("V" icon under the votes for the answer), this shows people that the question has a usable answer.

Comment: took me a bit of looking to find that...  it's a 'tick' I think, rather than a 'v'.  You call them 'ticks' in the US? Maybe a 'check' or something...